# Why can't my Postman find my Spring REST API?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, postman

I am doing simple request of getting one user by id by Postman. But response status is 200 and it is not returning anything.  However in my user table I have data. I thought that problem is with antMatchers but couldnt manage it. There is no log data in the console. i can access to other controllers but with this user controller there is a problem.  Why am I not able to connect to my backend? **I noticed smth weird. i used refreshKey in Authorization instead of tokenkey and it works. Should i leave it to be or using of toenkey in authorization is needed?**

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Ja9.png)

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    /*@Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }*/

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/type")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/nation")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/recept")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/recept/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ingredient")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/recept/{\\\\d+}")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

UserController

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/users",method= RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<UserResponse> getAllUsers(){
        return userService.getAllUsers().stream().map(u -> new UserResponse(u)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/users",method= RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        User user = userService.saveOneUser(newUser);
        if(user != null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users/{userId}",method= RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public UserResponse getOneUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        log.info (String.valueOf (userId));
        User user = userService.getOneUserById(userId);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException ();
        }
        return new UserResponse(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users/{userId}",method= RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateOneUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody User newUser) {
        User user = userService.updateOneUser(userId, newUser);
        if(user != null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users/{userId}",method= RequestMethod.DELETE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void deleteOneUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        userService.deleteById(userId);
    }

}
```

UserResponse

```
@Data
public class UserResponse {

    Long id;
    int avatarId;
    String userName;

    public UserResponse(User entity) {
        this.id = entity.getId();
        this.avatarId = entity.getAvatar();
        this.userName = entity.getUser_name ();
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwtToken = extractJwtFromRequest(request);
            if(StringUtils.hasText(jwtToken) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwtToken)) {
                Long id = jwtTokenProvider.getUserIdFromJwt(jwtToken);
                UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserById(id);
                if(user != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                    auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String extractJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearer = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(StringUtils.hasText(bearer) && bearer.startsWith("Bearer "))
            return bearer.substring("Bearer".length() + 1);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: A side note: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.  It's a minor pain to migrate off of (which is what I'm working on now) so if you can use a later version of Spring Security and follow something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: What does your service implementation look like?

Comment: here is a simple tutorial how to implement the handling of JWTs in spring https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: Its usual service with predetermined functions. The problem is that it even doesnt access controller. So the problem isnt in repository or service

Comment: can you please show your `UserResponse` class code? maybe the problem is it doesn't have getters so Jackson cannot serialize it as json. Postman's `1` response is a line number, which means request has reached your API, but Postman sees empty response body.

Comment: @AndrewThomas i added Data to UserResponse

Comment: ok, then please provide your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` classes code

Comment: @AndrewThomas I noticed smth weird. i used refreshKey in Authorization instead of tokenkey and it works. Should i leave it to be or using of toenkey in authorization is needed?

Comment: @WaterBaloon what does it even mean? :) I don't see any `tokenkey` or `refreshKey` vars in your code

Comment: @AndrewThomas in frontend I created localStorage that has tokenkey and refreshkey.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Any JUnit5 tests implemented to get automatisation testing for these kind of stuff.

2/ With postman you are using the port 8081, have you checked it in your application-{env}.properties twice ?

3/ Your are using `JwtAuthenticationFilter` did you configure properly your roles and users to authenticate yourself correctly.

4/ Did you checked your Bearer generated :

```
Bearer = Base64EncodedString(username:password); 
//Or a valid JWT token get with another authentication method, of course.
```

5/ You are not using any Spring Security annotation to access to your controller which is located inside a protected area by default.
Look at `@PreAuthorize` and `@Secured` annotations or alternatives.
Do not forget to activate them with `@EnableWebSecurity` in your Security configuration class (ie `WebSecurityConfig.java` or like).

Comment: 2) application properites is correct 4) I checked bearer from frontend it works. i could login and register.